# Looking for best mockup application

Tags: mocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What website wireframing tools are available online, or self-hosted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792217/what-website-wireframing-tools-are-available-online-or-self-hosted)

I have a very big web project (web site) and I am looking for good mockup application to help me design and architect the site.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this answer and the question
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14365/how-to-create-mockups-of-user-interfaces/14368#14368 You will find there many options

Comment: Duplicate of many other questions, just search for mock-up/wireframing tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) is used by lots of places and is considered to be easy to use.